# Firebase Hosting - Wildcard Redirections

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to use Firebase Hosting to host an angular application and I need to create a redirection to some old files in another URL.

According with the Firebase Documentation you can do basic redirections

```
"redirects": [ {
    "source" : "/foo",
    "destination" : "/bar",
    "type" : 301
}, {
    "source" : "/firebase/*",
    "destination" : "https://www.firebase.com",
    "type" : 302
} ]
```

But I need a wildcard redirection

```
"redirects": [ {
    "source" : "/config/*",
    "destination" : "//oldsiteurl/config/[match-request]",
    "type" : 302
}]
```

So, basically I need that `myapp.firebase.com/config/some.json` redirects to `//oldsiteurl/config/some.json`. I have a lot of json files so I do not want to match file by file.

Did you know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

For people landing on this page, it is now possible to have wildcards in the URLs:

> Sometimes it is desirable to capture parts of the source URL of a redirect and re-use them in the destination. You can do this using a `:` prefix to identify the segment and an optional `*` after the name to indicate that it should capture the rest of the URL

([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture-url-segments-for-redirects))

Answer (score 5):

```
"redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/subdomain/:random*",
        "destination": "https://subdomain.myapp.com/:random*",
        "type": 301
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Firebase documentation on URL redirects](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html) (emphasis mine):

> If a match is found, an HTTP redirect response is set with the "Location" header set to the **static** destination string, which can be a relative path or an absolute URL.

So it looks like the wild-carded part of the match is not carried over into the redirect.